# Send data from chosen Annotation (InfoBoule button)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a mapView which loads annotations with the help of a web service. I parse the data in json in an array and get the values of each annotation.

But now, I want to send the information of the annotation in selection.
As I can think, It mar rather be like the section in UITableView called DidSelectRow...

How I can do this?

Comment: What does InfoBoule mean?  Have you looked at the MKMapViewDelegate documentation?  There's a didSelectAnnotationView delegate method for example.  What have you tried and what's the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean when the user taps one of the annotations in mapView, you have a delegate method for that. From MKMapViewDelegate Protocol Reference

```
mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:
```

Set your view controller as delegate for your mapView and then just use this delegate method to be notified when the user taps on one of your annotations.

[Link to Apple Documentation on MKMapViewDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html)